# Flex Monkey issue

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I am trying to setup Flex Monkey.I am using Flex SDK 3.5. I added the Additional Compiler Arguments `-include-libraries "../libs/automation_monkey3.x.swc"`for my project in Flex Builder.Now when I runthe application and click on Username text box, I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at com.gorillalogic.aqadaptor::AQEnvironment/sortAncestors()[/Users/sstern/Documents/Projects/flexmonkey/MonkeyLink/src/com/gorillalogic/aqadaptor/AQEnvironment.as:328]
at Array$/_sort()
at Array/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::sort()
at com.gorillalogic.aqadaptor::AQEnvironment/findAllAncestors()[/Users/sstern/Documents/Projects/flexmonkey/MonkeyLink/src/com/gorillalogic/aqadaptor/AQEnvironment.as:302]
at com.gorillalogic.aqadaptor::AQEnvironment/findClosestAncestor()[/Users/sstern/Documents/Projects/flexmonkey/MonkeyLink/src/com/gorillalogic/aqadaptor/AQEnvironment.as:275]
at com.gorillalogic.aqadaptor::AQEnvironment/getAutomationClassByInstance()[/Users/sstern/Documents/Projects/flexmonkey/MonkeyLink/src/com/gorillalogic/aqadaptor/AQEnvironment.as:246]
at mx.automation::AutomationManager/helpCreateIDPart()[C:\work\flex\dmv_automation\projects\automation\src\mx\automation\AutomationManager.as:1880]
at mx.automation.delegates.core::ContainerAutomationImpl/createAutomationIDPart()[C:\work\flex\dmv_automation\projects\automation\src\mx\automation\delegates\core\ContainerAutomationImpl.as:185]
at mx.core::UIComponent/createAutomationIDPart()[C:\autobuild\3.5.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9299]
at mx.automation::AutomationManager/captureID()[C:\work\flex\dmv_automation\projects\automation\src\mx\automation\AutomationManager.as:2657]
at mx.automation::AutomationManager/captureIDFromMouseDownEvent()[C:\work\flex\dmv_automation\projects\automation\src\mx\automation\AutomationManager.as:2588]
```

When I remove the Additional Compiler Parameters, the application works fine. I am unable to fix this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I cleaned and recreated **html-template** folder in Flex builder, the error got resolved.Strange,but it works!